# CakePHP route redirect with parameters

Tags: redirect, cakephp, routes

I need to keep SEO links active so I'm trying to 301 redirect google trafic to new CakePHP route.

I go to:

```
http://localhost/jakne/someCategory/item-slug
```

And I want it to 301 redirect to:

```
http://localhost/product/item-slug
```

So I tried with `route::redirect` but I can't make it work. Doc on this is also non existent :(

```php
$routes->redirect(
    '/jakne/:subcategory/:item',
    ['controller' => 'Catalog', 'action' => 'product'],
    ['status' => 301, 'pass' => ['item']]
);
```

My `Catalog::product` looks like:

```php
public function product($productId) {
}
```

I always get error that no parameter was passed to the action.
What am I missing? :(

Comment: Gave up on this in the end and used nginx redirect as it sits in front of CakePHP app anyway

Answer (score 0):

The option for retaining parameters in redirect routes isn't `pass` (that's for regular routes and defines which parameters to pass as function arguments), it's `persist`, ie your route would need to be something like:

```php
$routes->redirect(
    '/jakne/:subcategory/:item',
    ['controller' => 'Catalog', 'action' => 'product'],
    ['status' => 301, 'persist' => ['item']]
);
```

This should work fine, assuming you have a proper target route connected that has a parameter named `item`, something like.

```php
$routes->connect(
    '/product/:item',
    ['controller' => 'Catalog', 'action' => 'product'],
    ['pass' => ['item']]
);
```

Generally you may want to consider doing such redirects on server level instead (for example via `mod_rewrite` on Apache), performance wise that's much better.

ps. Browsers do cache `301` redirects, so when making changes to such redirects, make sure that you clear the cache afterwards.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Redirect Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing)**

Comment: tried that before and it's not working. It redirects to /product?item=value which is not what I want :( Tried with htaccess rule and even that is not working. for some reason it redirects to domain.com/var/www/html/webroot/products/:item

Comment: @DavidLednik If it's appended as a query string, then you either do not have a matching target route as shown in my example, or there's another route connected that is catching it. If you can't figure it out, you may want to update your question with your complete routes configuration. btw, whenever you have routing problems, check which routes are connected in which order using [**the routes shell**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/routes-shell.html): `bin/cake routes`.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is quite simple. I use this to dynamically generate a list of redirects based on what admins enter in the control panel. We use this to keep google traffic when the URL changes and is not rescanned by the google bot yet.

```
$builder->redirect('/from-url', '/to-url', ['status' => 301]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ways it is working for me: 
Example request like: **localhost:08080/get-username?id=%3Cid%3E**

Routes :

```
$routes->connect('/get-username', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'getUserName']);
```

Controller :

```
    class UsersController extends AppController {
       public function initialize() {
          parent::initialize();
           $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
       }

       public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
          parent::beforeFilter($event);
          $this->set('_serialize', false);
          $this->Auth->allow([
            'getUserName'
          ]);
       }

       public function getUserName() {
        $id = $this->request->getQuery('id');

       }
   }
```